# How to get rid of the blue image border under the "<a" element for IE8?

Tags: html, css

When I use `<a>` element the tooltip works fine . Here is the code :

```
 <html>
<head>
<style>
a.tooltip {outline:none; }
a.tooltip strong {line-height:30px;}
a.tooltip:hover {text-decoration:none;} 
a.tooltip span {
    z-index:10;display:none; padding:14px 20px;
    margin-top:-30px; margin-left:28px;
    width:300px; line-height:16px;
}
a.tooltip:hover span{
    display:inline; position:absolute; color:#111;
    border:1px solid #DCA; background:#fffAF0;}
.callout {z-index:20;position:absolute;top:30px;border:0;left:-12px;}

/*CSS3 extras*/
a.tooltip span
{
    border-radius:4px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 8px #CCC;
}
a { 
    color: blue;
} 
</style>           
</head>

<body>  
<br><br>
<a href='#' class='tooltip'>
<img src='http://www.hasitleaked.portmerch.com/stores/hasitleaked_provider/images/search_button.gif'></img>
    <span>
      Quick description 
    </span>
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is because of the `<a` element, The `IE8` shows blue boarder of that image. This boarder does not exist, I don't know why, but other browsers work fine. I want to get rig of the image blue border. How can I do this ? I tried not to use `<a` but it did't work

Comment: img { border: none; }

Comment: Thank You! Other browsers were working fine. IE freaks me out Thanks !!!

Comment: That `img` needs null alt text (i.e. `alt=""`). See http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H67

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must  try

```
img, a {border:none, outline: none;}
```